# Can I choose two answers for my question as the accepted answer(s)?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

So, on my last question I got two answers that helped me the most.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93158/42857

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93150/42857

Do I have to accept only one of them as the best answer or can I accept both?

Comment: Please note that you don't *have* to accept any answer. It's your choice to accept an answer or not depending on whether it was helpful or not. I am only saying this because there are quite often people who assume that you really *have* to accept an answer.

Comment: See for example [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1820/28789)

Answer (score 7):

This has been requested more than a few times since [the early years of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/274942). Part of the reason it keeps getting brought up again is that more SE sites deal with topics where there's more than one solution to any given problem; Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is one of these sites. Therefore, sometimes two answers can be similarly helpful.

The request is currently [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and will probably stay that way (to answer your question). You can, of course, reward multiple answers with bounties, but make sure you [read about them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/274942) before starting one. You can also compile information into a single answer, but I don't see that happen very often, to be frank.

Comment: Ok...apparently I wasn't reading carefully enough when I went through your answer, I could have sworn you didn't have bounties mentioned...so my answers is completely superfluous. But I got to type superfluous so that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

HDE pretty much covers the relevant information regarding the topic.  No, and its not likely to ever happen.  That said there is a way to show appreciation for other answers that help you out.

**BOUNTIES! :)**

Bounties are a great way to give some reputation to an answer that was really good/helpful but didn't quite get to be the 'selected' answer.

Bounties essentially offer people some of your own hard earned rep as a thank you their work.  Given you are new you don't have a ton to work with so I am throwing up a bounty for you.  Just pay it forward in the future.

Let me know who your second place answer is.

Comment: thank you ^_^ My second choice is Ash https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93150/42857   this totally solves my dilema.

Comment: errrr... what do I do now? I mean, if I select A.G. Weyland and then try to mark Ash as well the first becomes desselected.

Comment: @shieldedtulip Any given question can only ever have a single (or no) answer selected as the accepted answer. Bounties are separate, and are awarded by the user who initiated them (with some exceptions based on community voting if that user doesn't make a choice as to which answer to award the bounty to).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Got it. Thank you. Was becomming confused lol . So I'll check my selected answer and then James will award the bounty to Ash, if he so chooses. (y)

Comment: @shieldedtulip Not a problem.  Welcome to the site.